# Google Web Fonts

Tags: html, css, fonts, google-font-api

I'm planning to use Google web fonts on my site.
My site has lots of pages, but only a few CSS files.
**-=>** Is there any way to add this tag in the CSS file (because I don't want to edit all the HTML files)?

```
<link href=' http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

or do I need to add the above line in every HTML page's head section?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep, [@import](http://www.studiopress.com/tips/google-web-fonts.htm) the google font in - [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/QXtc6/1/)

Put this at the **top** of your CSS file

```
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans');
```

Then, reference it like normal

```
h1 { font-family: 'Droid Sans', arial, serif; font-size:24pt;}
```

Comment: It is worth noting that @import affects performance and should be avoided, see https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rtt#AvoidCssImport and http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#csslink for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Add the tags, how? Please explain yourself better.

In the HTML you can do this…

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
  h1 { font-family: 'Droid Sans', arial, serif; }
</style>
```

If that's what you're asking?