# How do I link directly to a .woff font file?

Tags: css, auth0

I am trying to link to this font: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Press+Start+2P?query=2 to update the styling on our authentication page using `Auth0`. The page asks for URL and stipulates:

> This URL must point directly to a woff or woff2 font file.

Not sure how to do this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Web Fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721766/google-web-fonts)

Comment: When I try that solution i get ``"Font URL" must begin with "https" and point directly to a "woff" or "woff2" file.``

Comment: how did you end up solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way you can directly call a google hosted font like that.
You can download it and host it in some cdn and serve from there or add it to your local.