# Custom Font On Shopify Not Loading On Safari Browser

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

Hope everyone is good.

Problem is my shopify store has custom font "IntegralCF-Regular" embedded and used but the font is not showing up correctly in safari. Here is my code in "custom.css":

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'IntegralCF-Regular' ;
    src: local('https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0561/3898/9704/files/IntegralCF-Regular.woff?v=1645097830'), local('Integral-CF-Regular'),
        url('https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0561/3898/9704/files/IntegralCF-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
   font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
  }


@font-face{font-family:'IntegralCF-Regular' ;
           src:url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0561/3898/9704/files/IntegralCF-Regular.woff?v=1645097830) format('woff');
           font-weight:600;
           font-style:italic;}




  .header-wrapper span, .footer-section h4, .footer-section p, .footer-section span, .footer-section button#Subscribe-footer-newsletter-section, .footer-section li {
    font-family: IntegralCF-Regular;
     src: local('https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0561/3898/9704/files/IntegralCF-Regular.woff?v=1645097830'), local('Integral-CF-Regular'),
        url('https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0561/3898/9704/files/IntegralCF-Regular.woff2') format('woff2');
}
```

Comment: Does it work in all other major browsers? (Chrome, Firefox, Edge) be sure to [clear the cache](https://support.planwithvoyant.com/hc/en-us/articles/360046611171-How-to-do-hard-refresh-in-Chrome-Firefox-Safari-and-Microsoft-Edge) before verifying.

Comment: @Yarin_007 Yes, working on all the major browsers. Only problem is on Safari

Comment: mmm. maybe [this](https://renatello.com/font-face-font-display/)?  `font-display: swap;`

Comment: @Yarin_007 tried the above solution but didn't worked

Comment: Check code
'@font-face {
    font-family: 'IntegralCF-Regular' ;
    src: local('https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0561/3898/9704/files/IntegralCF-Regular.woff?v=1645097830'), local('Integral-CF-Regular'),
        url('https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0561/3898/9704/files/IntegralCF-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
   font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap; 
  }'

Comment: '@font-face{font-family:'IntegralCF-Regular' ;
           src:url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0561/3898/9704/files/IntegralCF-Regular.woff?v=1645097830) format('woff');
           font-weight:600;
           font-style:italic;
          font-display: swap; 
          }
'

Comment: '  .header-wrapper span, .footer-section h4, .footer-section p, .footer-section span, .footer-section button#Subscribe-footer-newsletter-section, .footer-section li {
    font-family: IntegralCF-Regular;
     src: local('https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0561/3898/9704/files/IntegralCF-Regular.woff?v=1645097830'), local('Integral-CF-Regular'),
        url('https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0561/3898/9704/files/IntegralCF-Regular.woff2') format('woff2');
    font-display: swap; 
}'

Comment: Does it happen with other fonts as well?

Comment: @Yarin_007 I didn't tried with other fonts. only this one is used.

Comment: ... yeah so try with others. that way you'll be able to tell if the problem is with your code / browser or with the font file. try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6721805/4935162) simple example and report back.